# FB.ActivateApp() not showing installs on fb dashboard

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I'm losing my mind here. Using the facebook unity sdk, i call init(), then on init callback i call FB.ActivateApp(), and FB.AppEvents.LogEvent(Facebook.FBAppEventName.ActivatedApp) for good measure, and i'll be damned if i can reliably see any events being reported on the dashboard.

There seem to be plenty of posts of people having similar issues, many left unanswered for a long time, others with useless suggestions. One says FB app needs to be installed. Does it? Is that in the documentation somewhere? And isn't that a really lame requirement since people can use FB in a browser?

When I didn't have FB installed, sure enough i get an exception: "No attribution id available to send to server". Does that mean the event is just completely dropped?

On ActivateApp I get this in the log, but it's labeled 'D', so I'm guessing not serious, and not sure what i could possibly do about it in the context of a Unity app:

D/com.facebook.AppEventsLogger(30663): To set source application the context of activateApp must be an instance of Activity

On logEvent the log just shows this:

AppEvents({"logEvent":"fb_mobile_activate_app"})

Which looks promising, yet nothing shows up in dashboard. I mean, i've launched on a bunch of devices, and relaunched a bunch of times, and i have a mere 3 'App Launches' activities showing up in the "Show Most Recent Events" popup. Just enough to know that the app is set up correctly with correct app id.

For the love of God, why can't a $200 billion dollar company make a plugin that actually works?! Or at least pay some support staff to actually help people on this forsaken forum!!

Final note, I've also tried the Prime31 socialnetworking plugin, which supposedly calls ActivateApp on init(), but it also doesn't report anything to dashboard. And calling logEvent manually null pointers. Lovely...

Comment: Well, after that long rant, it looks like my events actually showed up the next day. But given the text in the "Show most recent events", i think i was justified in expecting near real time data:


`When this page is open, this table displays events that are logged more than 1 second after the most recently displayed event`

And debug statements like this question whether anything is working: `D/com.facebook.AppEventsLogger(24931): To set source application the context of activateApp must be an instance of Activity`

Comment: Now with the Facebook SDK version v7.13.0, I still meet this problem which make me confused and depressed. I always think I do something wrong and check the steps again and again because I think FB can not have mistake. And now my dash board still have nothing record. Maybe time is not enough to one day. I have find nothing document about this, and even should I call  `FB.LogAppEvent(AppEventName.ActivatedApp)` when I have called 
 `FB.ActivateApp()`; No reference and when I find your post, I just hope I have good luck when today is past and my dashboard has something.